# Where is the work directory of embedded tomcat for a spring boot / spring mvc application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I would like to ask where is the location where you can see the work directory of a  spring boot / spring mvc applicaiton. Specifically I want to know Transpiled JSP files converted to java files.

I can see the class files inside the target directory, but cannot find the transpiled jsp files. Is there a class call where I can see it in my environment? Like `System.getProperty("user.dir")` or new `java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath()`. I tried both and it only showed me the code path.

Also, I know the Eclipse Server path. But in spring boot, it does not seem to run using a server instance of tomcat. So the following path is not existing?

The following directory is also blank.

> projectworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base dir is set via the property `server.tomcat.basedir`, see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html

The work dir is derrived from there by appending `/work`.